# UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector Crash

Tags: ios, iphone, crash, uikit

I get some random crashes - at the moment only on iPhone 14 Pro Max Devices. Heres the backtrace of the cash.

```
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18c262d94 __exceptionPreprocess + 164 (NSException.m:202)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1853143d0 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:356)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x18c3d7b14 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 136 (NSObject.m:140)
3   UIKitCore                       0x18f03006c -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 260 (UIResponder.m:698)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x18c2791c8 ___forwarding___ + 1592 (NSForwarding.m:3578)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x18c2df9f0 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 96 (:-1)
6   UIKitCore                       0x18ebb2e40 -[UIKeyboardSceneDelegate enhancedWindowingModeIsEnabled] + 32 (UIKeyboardSceneDelegate.m:3005)
7   UIKitCore                       0x18ec2fd24 -[UIKeyboardVisualModeManager windowingModeEnabled] + 80 (UIKeyboardVisualModeManager.m:237)
8   UIKitCore                       0x18ec2f6f8 -[UIKeyboardVisualModeManager visualMode] + 60 (UIKeyboardVisualModeManager.m:96)
9   UIKitCore                       0x18ec2fc44 -[UIKeyboardVisualModeManager keyboardCameraNotification:] + 216 (UIKeyboardVisualModeManager.m:222)
10  CoreFoundation                  0x18c290670 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 148 (CFNotificationCenter.c:661)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x18c334910 ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 88 (CFNotificationCenter.c:175)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x18c3179a8 _CFXRegistrationPost + 440 (CFNotificationCenter.c:201)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x18c2a4bdc _CFXNotificationPost + 700 (CFNotificationCenter.c:1193)
14  Foundation                      0x186584e28 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 92 (NSNotification.m:518)
15  UIKitCore                       0x18ee406c0 -[UIKeyboardCameraSession _keyboardCameraPreparationDidComplete] + 88 (UIKeyboardCameraSession.m:353)
16  UIKitCore                       0x18ee40644 __32-[UIKeyboardCameraSession _show]_block_invoke + 40 (UIKeyboardCameraSession.m:341)
17  UIKitCore                       0x18f27588c __56-[UIKeyboardCameraViewController prepareWithCompletion:]_block_invoke + 720 (UIKeyboardCameraViewController.m:212)
18  UIKitCore                       0x18e7d0870 __146-[NSExtension(UIViewControllerAdditions) _instantiateViewControllerWithInputItems:asAccessory:traitCollection:listenerEndpoint:connectionHandler:]_block_invoke_3 + 220 (NSExtension_UIKitAdditions.m:89)
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x193720320 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1518)
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x193721eac _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x1937306a4 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 928 (inline_internal.h:2640)
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x1937302f4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44 (queue.c:7954)
23  CoreFoundation                  0x18c2f1d18 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16 (CFRunLoop.c:1780)
24  CoreFoundation                  0x18c2d3650 __CFRunLoopRun + 1992 (CFRunLoop.c:3147)
25  CoreFoundation                  0x18c2d84dc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612 (CFRunLoop.c:3418)
26  GraphicsServices                0x1c752c35c GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2196)
27  UIKitCore                       0x18e66437c -[UIApplication _run] + 888 (UIApplication.m:3773)
28  UIKitCore                       0x18e663fe0 UIApplicationMain + 340 (UIApplication.m:5363)
```

Can anyone give me a hint to find a solution for this issue.
Loading the Crash into Xcode brings me only in the AppDelegate.